# creating key/value hash out of array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, data-structures, hash

I came across an old piece of code which was creating the hash datatype using simple arrays in ruby. I get most of it, except one part:

The point as I understand it is, every element of `@store` is a memory location for a particular key/value pair, as a function of the key. So `@store[3]` would generally store key/value pairs corresponding to key=3, key=53, ... and in general where `key % size == 3` (in this case size = 50).

However, when I set `hash[3] = 7`, `hash[53] = 9`, etc., every element of `@store` array is populated with the key/value pairs, and not just the index 3 element. It seems like the line `@store[store_key] << [key, value]` in the method `[]=(key, value)` is adding [key, value] to every element of `@store`, and not just one with the index `store_key`. Any ideas?

```
class SimpleHash
  attr_accessor :size, :store

  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @store = Array.new(size, [])
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    store_key = key % @size
    index = find_key(key, @store[store_key])
    if index
      @store[store_key][index][1] = value
    else
      p "***********************************"
      p @store
      @store[store_key] << [key, value]
      p "after"
      p store_key
      p @store
    end
  end
end

hash = SimpleHash.new(50)
p hash
hash[3] = 5
p hash
hash[3] = 7
hash[53] = 9
hash[103] = 11
hash[104] = 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
@store = Array.new(size){ [] }
```

Every element is a separate array.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question's a bit unclear, I can guess what the problem is.

```
@store = Array.new(size, [])
```

That creates an array of the right size, but where every element is the SAME OBJECT.

Change the array-within-an-array at any position, and the change will be evident in every position.

Try instead

```
@store = Array.new
size.times { @store << [] }
```

Every sub-array will be a separate object that way.

EDIT

@nafaa boutefer's answer is better. The block gets evaluated for each instance of the array so each sub-array is a different object.

```
@store = Array.new(size){ [] }
```

Comment: Had to edit this, sorry!  My original solution wasn't working :/

Comment: This is highly un-idiomatic. The idiomatic way would be to use the block form of [`Array::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) as in [@Nafaa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28580232/2988).